# How to deserialize a Json string in c#

Tags: json, c#-4.0

I have this Json string in memory, and trying to deserialize into a class :

```
{
  { "Member_ColName": "Entity Name" , "Member_Key": "entityName" },
  { "Margin_ColName": "Margin", "Margin_Key": "Margin" },
  { "LookBack_ColName": "Lookback Interval (Days)", "LookBack_Key":"LookbackInterval"},
{ "ConfInterval": "Confidence Interval"," ConfInterval_Key": "ConfidenceInterval"}
```

}

My public class is defined as :

```
public class JsonParameters
{
    string Member_ColName { get; set; }
    string Member_Key { get; set; }
    string Margin_ColName { get; set; }
    string Margin_Key { get; set; }
    string LookBack_ColName { get; set; }
    string LookBack_Key { get; set; }
    string ConfInterval { get; set; }
    string ConfInterval_Key { get; set; }
}
```

My c# method is as follows:

```
             public string getJsonParameters()
    {
         // file stream code omitted
        JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        string jsonStr = utf.GetString(buffer);
        Classes.JsonParameters jsonData = (Classes.JsonParameters)ser.Deserialize(jsonStr, typeof(Classes.JsonParameters));


        return jsonStr;
    }
```

I've done this kind of thing before when reading in a string of dates, but I did something slightly different.
In this case I can't seem to deserialize the Json object.

Any advice would be appreciated.

thanks.
Bob

Comment: You're json text doesn't seem to have the correct definition. The json should follow something like this for that object definition: `{"Member_ColName": "Entity Name" , "Member_Key": "entityName" , "Margin_ColName": "Margin", "Margin_Key": "Margin" , "LookBack_ColName": "Lookback Interval (Days)", "LookBack_Key":"LookbackInterval", "ConfInterval": "Confidence Interval"," ConfInterval_Key": "ConfidenceInterval"}` Also you've got a space in `" ConfInter`

Comment: thx for responding. I'm still getting a "Invalid JSON primitive:" even after fixing the format as per your suggestion. I'll keep investigating...

Comment: As far as I can see you've your json completely mixedup with your class definition and so it can be deserialized.